# Unwrapping in guard clause

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

I have this function that uses `guard` to make sure the parameters are correct:

```
func foo(bundle: NSBundle?, _ url: NSURL?)->Bool{

    guard let _ = url, let _ = bundle  else{
        print("crap")
        return false
    }


    return true
}
```

I noticed that the else clause will run if ANY of the parameters is nil. It behaves as an OR clause.

However, what I need is to check that BOTH are nil (an AND).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually care about your bound values (which I assume you don't, given the `_` names), you can do this:

```
func foo(bundle: NSBundle?, _ url: NSURL?) -> Bool {
    guard url != nil || bundle != nil else {
        print("crap")
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

If you do actually want to bind the values, then you cannot accomplish this with a single `guard` statement.  If it fails to unwrap a value from either of the optionals then it will execute the `else` block, as you've noted.

If you were still set on using a guard statement, you would have to put in a guard as I have above followed by various `if let` statements to unwrap things as appropriate (or just omit the guard and have an else statement in the code below that was the false case):

```
func foo(bundle: NSBundle?, _ url: NSURL?) -> Bool {
    guard url != nil || bundle != nil else {
        print("crap")
        return false
    }

    if url == nil, let someBundle = bundle {
        // Handle the bundle only case
    }
    else if bundle == nil, let someUrl = url {
        // Handle the url only case
    }
    else if let someUrl = url, let someBundle = bundle {
        // Handle the case for both
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a job for a guard statement. What you want is:

```
if(url == nil && bundle == nil)
{
    print("crap")
    return false
}
return true
```